# Can we run multiple feature files in the same package using Karate-gatling

Tags: karate

I read in the documentation that we can run multiple feature files by adding newer lines for different classpaths in the simulation class. Is there a way wherein we can run multiple feature files belonging to the same package just like we run in FeatureRunner files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I personally think that will introduce maintainability issues. We will consider PR-s though if anyone wants to contribute this.

If you really want this behavior, you should be able to write a small bit of Java code that scans a folder, loops over them and builds the Gatling "scenarios".